# uploading an image in swift 4.2 with imagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to upload an image with ImagePickerController to a Rails Backend using the  in Swift 4.2 using Alamofire. The problem I am facing is that the image must only upload when pressing a register button. Below is my imagePickerController function. The Alamofire part should be done in the handleRegister function. The question is: how do I store the picked image in the local storage of the device (userDefaults) and use the Alamofire upload image in the handleRegister function?

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        registrationViewModel.bindableImage.value = image
        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "account[user_attributes[profile_picture]]", fileName: "user_profile_picture.png", mimeType: "image/jpeg"); for(key, value) in self.parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, to: URL_REGISTER,
           headers: nil)
        {(result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: {(Progress) in
                    print("Upload progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    } else {
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}




@objc fileprivate func handleRegister() {
    self.handleTapDismiss()
    guard let username = userNameTextField.text else {return}
    guard let email = emailTextField.text else {return}
    guard let password = passwordTextField.text else {return}

    registeringHUD.textLabel.text = "Register"
    registeringHUD.show(in: view)


    AuthService.instance.registerUser(email: email, password: password, username: username) { (success) in
        if success {
            print("user has signed up")

            // only upload images to backend once you are authorized

        } else {
            self.showHUDWithError()
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI - you don't store the image in UserDefaults. Write the image to a file.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for your answer. I'm new to swift programming :$, do you have an example of this that will apply to my above code? – sammyO